# Tesseract in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, ocr, tesseract, tess-two

To test *Tesseract* in a simple app found in this [tutorial](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/#comment-183696) , I need to import it in Android Studio. I get this error:

> Library reference ....\tess\tess-two could not be found

How I can solve this  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the line

```
android.library.reference.1=../../tess/tess-two
```

in the `project.properties` file properly.

This line makes reference to the tess-two library.

Alternative way: remove `android.library.reference.1=...` line and after importing your project just make referencing to the `tess-two` library project as described [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) (in ADT)

Comment: I try this and make same error. 
this link for eclipse !

Comment: editing 'android.library.reference.1=..' line makes same error too?

Answer (score 0):

Get `tess-two` with

```
git clone https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two.git tess
```

and put tess in the right place where your main module can find it.